# Eclipse compiler error on simple Java class

Tags: java

I am facing a problem while i am trying to compile a code at eclipse in java. The code is the following:

```
public class New {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Parts that have errors are `New`, `String` and `System`. I have checked at error list and the description for error's is like:

1. Unable to create editor ID
2. The file does not exist

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @ZaoTaoBao: `new` is a keyword - `New` isn't.

Comment: "Unable to create editor ID" isn't a compiler error. It's an Eclipse platform error. Can you reproduce this by creating `New.java` in a different project? I can't reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project has or classes maybe has beeing dissapeared.

I can give you a possible solution

Solution: Shut down Eclipse IDE  Start Eclipse IDE (with -clean to be super-safe) Reimport all projects (UPDATE: Just use File->Import->Existing Project into Workspace and browse your workspace/project directory)

Comment: I tried as you said but the error remain..any other ideas ?

thanks anyway

Comment: Yes...Check this!. if the words New, String and System gives error compile, check if you have the libraries inserted in your project. Maybe, you has forgotten to insert the jre library. Could be a probability..

Comment: Oh...actually i just installed the eclipse and tried to write a code i did not import any libraries do you have a link that i can find them ?

Comment: From your Eclipse workspace, right click your project on the left pane -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add Jars -> add your jars here. Check what kind of libraries do you need. Check if jre system library is already inserted.

Comment: I am new in java and eclipse also i don't have any tutorials and i dont know what "jars" are so i can add them...Can you explain me with more simple way ?